# Facebook Fan Page Cover Image Change

Tags: facebook, api

I am looking forward to develop an application by using php and facebook sdk, so that I can change the cover image of a fan page.

I am the admin of the app that I have created and using the same appId and appSecret for the same.

Here I am posting my source code, any help will be appreciated.

It throws exception "Uncaught OAuthException: (#10) Application does not have permission for this action"

```
    require 'php-sdk/facebook.php';
    $app_id = "My App ID";
    $app_secret = "My App Secret";
    $post_login_url = "URL";


    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $app_id,
      'secret' => $app_secret,
      'cookie' => true
    ));


    $user_fb = $facebook->getUser();

    if($user_fb == 0)
    {
        $user_fb = $facebook->getUser();
    }

    if ($user_fb) 
    {   
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me'); 
        $user_friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends'); 
        $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(); 

    }
    else 
    {     
         $perms = array('scope' => 'user_photos,photo_upload,manage_pages,publish_stream', 'redirect_uri' => '');
         $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($perms);        
         echo "<script>top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "'</script>";        
    }

    $pageIds=$facebook->api('/me/accounts');
    $pageAccessToken=$pageIds["data"][1]["access_token"]; 

    $facebook->setAccessToken($pageAccessToken);



    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

    //Create an album
    $album_details = array(
            'message'=> 'My New Album',
            'name'=> 'My New Album'
    );
    $create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);

    $album_uid = $create_album['id'];

    $photo_details = array(
        'message'=> 'Testing facebook API'
    );
    $file='images/Tanveer1.png'; 
    $photo_details['image'] = '@' . realpath($file);
    $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);

    $make_cover_image = array(
        'cover'=> $upload_photo['id'],
        'offset_y'=> '60',
    );

    $json_object = $facebook->api("/Fan_Page_ID/?access_token=".$pageAccessToken,'post',$make_cover_image);

    print_r($json_object);
```

Comment: On which action do you get that exception? When getting list of pages? Creating album?

Comment: Hi Darvex, I am able to create Album and add the pics in it, but it appears under my profiles photo album. Actually I have create a fan page linked with my facebook profile and want to change the cover image of that account. It throws except at $json_object = $facebook->api("504052382999258/?access_token=".$pageAccessToken,'post',$make_cover_image);

Comment: Hmm, my guess would be that ?access_token part is not necessary since you've already set that access_token previously via ->setAccessToken. So i'd say remove that part and leave just /PAGE_ID/. If that doesn't help you can add "access_token" => $pageAccessToken to your $make_cover_image and try it that way.

Comment: It still not working, it throws error " Uncaught OAuthException: (#10) Application does not have permission for this action thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fbinn\php-sdk\base_facebook.php on line 1039"

Comment: Do you have any working code in php to change the cover image of facebook fan page?

Comment: I'm afraid i don't. I'd suggest you debugging a little. See if you're getting right page's access token, make sure the data you're sending is correct etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am trying my level best to rectified it.

Comment: Hi Friends, Any body had any working code to post an image on a facebook fan page and make it cover image for the same page? Please help me its urgent.